# Ckeditor toolbar how to set custom name on format-dropdown

Tags: ckeditor

Just updated Ckeditor to 4.6 and implemented it with inline-editor.
Most config works fine.

But in my toolbar, I have Format. But instead of showing 'Normal (DIV)' and 'Normal', I want to show 'Normal 1' and 'Normal 2'.

I did this before by writing this in my config:

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
config.format_tags = "div;p;h1;h2;h3;h4;h5;h6;pre;address";

config.format_div = { element: 'div', name: 'Normal 1.0' };
config.format_p = { element: 'p', name: 'Normal 2.0' };
```

For some reason, this does not work after the update. The dropdown in the toolbar does not show 'Normal 1.0' and 'Normal 2.0'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it stopped working after I changed the editor to inline.
Fixed it directly by changing the name in the language file. Worked for me since the words are the same in all languages.